# resetForm() doesn't call unhighlight

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to call unhighlight when i call resetForm(). Is there a way to do that?

```
$('#coupon_submit_btn').on('click',function(){
  .....
  $('#coupon_code').val("");
  validator.resetForm(); ......
```

EDIT:

where validator is my form that I validate

```
var validator = $('#checkout_form_payment').validate({ rules......
```

Comment: What is `validator`? :)

Comment: The form that i validate, where the rules and the highlight are.

Comment: Well, then what is `validate`? It's definitely not a jquery core API.

Comment: He's using jQuery Validate.

Comment: Why do you need to call `unhighlight`? All it does is remove the error class, and the resetForm() function also removes the error class.

Comment: because in my highlight class, there's error icons that show up. unhighlight removes them. That's why :P

Comment: So what you mean to say is that you're overriding the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions?

Comment: It would be helpful information for you to add your overriden `hightlight` and `unhighlight` functions to your question.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, if you want to have `resetForm()` call `unhighlight()`, you can add the following to your JS:

```
$.validator.prototype.resetForm = function() {
    if ( $.fn.resetForm ) {
        $(this.currentForm).resetForm();
    }
    this.submitted = {};
    this.lastElement = null;
    this.prepareForm();
    this.hideErrors();
    var elements = this.elements().removeData("previousValue").removeAttr("aria-invalid");
    if (this.settings.unhighlight) {
        for (var i = 0; elements[i]; i++) {
            this.settings.unhighlight.call(this, elements[i], this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass);
        }
    }
}
```

This will replace replace the existing `resetForm()` with one that replicates the existing `resetForm()` behaviour, but swaps the code that removes the error class with instead calling `unhighlight()` on each element.

Comment: It was applied in the commit https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/903 and it will be available in the next release 1.13.2 (not yet available).